# using bundler to load different versions of gems for different platforms

Tags: ruby, git, sinatra, bundler

So I am developing a Sinatra for both windows and linux.  The problem is I'm using Thin instead of Webrick and eventmachine for windows only works with a pre-release version while linux uses the latest stable.  in the gemfile you of course cannot include the same gem with different versions like so:

```
gem "eventmachine", "~> 1.0.0.beta.4.1", :group => :development_win
gem "eventmachine", group => :development_linux
gem "thin
```

I was wondering if there was a way to work around this, maybe using one gemfile for windows and one gemfile for linux, what would the command be to load one or the other.

Alternatively is there a way to perhaps in git manage just the gemfile for two different platforms, perhaps through a branch for just the file (don't know if that's possible from what I've read of git branches).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
# Windows
gem "eventmachine", "~> 1.0.0.beta.4.1", :platform => [:mswin, :mingw]

# C Ruby (MRI) or Rubinius, but NOT Windows
gem "eventmachine", :platform => :ruby
```

Full list of available platforms:

```
ruby      C Ruby (MRI) or Rubinius, but NOT Windows
ruby_18   ruby AND version 1.8
ruby_19   ruby AND version 1.9
ruby_20   ruby AND version 2.0
mri       Same as ruby, but not Rubinius
mri_18    mri AND version 1.8
mri_19    mri AND version 1.9
mri_20    mri AND version 2.0
rbx       Same as ruby, but only Rubinius (not MRI)
jruby     JRuby
mswin     Windows
mingw     Windows 'mingw32' platform (aka RubyInstaller)
mingw_18  mingw AND version 1.8
mingw_19  mingw AND version 1.9
mingw_20  mingw AND version 2.0
```

You can find more information in `Gemfile(5)` man page [here](http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/gemfile.5.html) (see 'Platforms' section).

Another approach is to use `RUBY_PLATFORM` constant:

```
if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /win32/
  gem "eventmachine", "~> 1.0.0.beta.4.1"
else
  gem "eventmachine"
end
```

I haven't seen full list of available values for `RUBY_PLATFORM` but you can run

```
ruby -e 'puts RUBY_PLATFORM'
```

on both your platforms and see the difference.

Comment: hmm, the first solution throws the same error about having two gems specified in the gemfile.  The conditional statement works fine.

Comment: And the second approach is invalid, as it stores one or another gem version into the `Gemfile.lock`. It can't store both. Thus if you prepare the `Gemfile.lock` on a Win32 dev machine then deploy it to Linux, you'll get the same wrong version.

Thus I'm still looking for a valid solution.

Comment: The :platform approach works well provided that only different (named) gems are needed for different platforms, it is even possible to commit the Gemfile.lock and keeping it stable (unlike the if-else approach)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the --gemfile option to use different gemfiles for different platforms. See the documentation here 
http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-config.1.html

Comment: I assume: 1. by 'different gemfiles' you mean 'different `Gemfile`s' (not 'different gem files'); and 2. by `--gemfile` you mean the `gemfile` configuration setting either in environment variable `BUNDLE_GEMFILE` or in the file `.bundle/config` (in developers' home directories). Thus Bundler safely could create e.g. `Gemfile-linux.lock` and `Gemfile-windows.lock`.

Answer (score 0):

You need multiple versions (all with the same name) of a gem. Therefore, currently with Bundler, you need multiple, simultaneous Bundler dependency snapshot 'lock' files. This is possible, if your developers make use of Bundler's `gemfile` configuration setting. They might do this either:

1. By making use of environment variable `BUNDLE_GEMFILE` (on the command line or in `.bash_profile`); or
2. (Probably less desirably) in `.bundle/config` (globally, in their home directories).

Thus, safely, Bundler can create (and presumably automatically later use, given the same configuration settings) e.g. `Gemfile-linux.lock` and `Gemfile-windows.lock`.

Although this basic approach seems workable, it's not very DRY. However, this improves if, e.g., both `Gemfile-linux` and `Gemfile-windows` automatically incorporate whatever Gemfile statements they share in common: i.e., if they include the statement:

`::Kernel.eval(File.open('Gemfile-common','r'){|f| f.read},::Kernel.binding)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I haven't used Ruby in years, but I am sure the answer in 2012 was satisfactory.